# MVC 3 - Accessing ModelMetaData for IEnumerable Model?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, html-helper, modelmetadata

I'm trying to access the ModelMetaData for a Custom HtmlHelper that I'm working on. The HtmlHelper has a signature like so ...

```
public static MvcHtmlString DataGrid<T>(this HtmlHelper<T> htmlHelper){}
```

The (Razor) View looks like this ...

```
@model IEnumerable<LogMyAssets.Models.ContactModel>
....
@Html.DataGrid()
```

My problem is that I can't access the ModelMetaData for the Model as it's IEnumerable. I thought I
could do the following:

```
var model = (IEnumerable<T>)htmlHelper.ViewData.Model;
var metaData = model.ElementAt(0).GetMetadata();

public static ModelMetadata GetMetadata<TModel>(this TModel model)
{
   return ModelMetadataProviders.Current.GetMetadataForType(null, typeof(TModel));
}
```

But stangely enough I get the following error:

```
Unable to cast object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[LMA.Models.ContactModel]' 
to type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1
```

I though I could could cast from Generic List to Generic IEnumerable. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand where the `T` is defined in `(IEnumerable<T>)`, however my Guess is that `T` is already `IEnumerable<something>`, which means you're trying to cast to `IEnumerable<IEnumerable<something>>`